# Is it possible to re-use a 7 inches TFT Display on Raspberry-Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd, display, tft

I'm trying to re-use a display I recovered from an old digital photo frame as a display for a Raspberry Pi.
The display is a TFT 7" LCD with backlight, but it comes with a 26-pin flat cable for which I couldn't find the pinout.
I also googled for some information on the display model (HLY070ML254-09A) with no success.
On the photo frame PCB there's no much information either.
This is the display: [image: display - front]
This is the back of it: [image: display - back]>br>
This is the detail of the label with model and serial no.: [image: display label]
This is how the 26-pin flat cable looks like: [image: flat cable]
On its back side there's also a label with a code: [image: flat cable back]
On the display side, the cable oddly has 63 pins: [image: flat cable display side]

My question is if there's a way to find the pins out or maybe someone has any clues that could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: `is it possible?` and `is there a way?` always has a `yes` answer, that makes such questions not very useful for arriving to any problem solution ... that said, you have to ask yourself if you want to spend the money and the time needed to develop an interface

Comment: Yeah, I mean, if I'm asking for information on the pinout it's implied that I'd invest time and money to do it myself... It would help if there's a driver board available but couldn't find any. The weirdest thing to me is the pinout of this board.

Comment: A new display is $50-$100. That means you will "save" money by "fixing" this one according to the value of your labor. If you're worth $10/hr, that only gives you  5-10 hours to get this working. I could see a project like this easily taking 100 hours, so to me, it's not even close to being worth it. Use a standard module with actual documentation. It was worth asking, not a bad question, but the answer sucks.

Comment: This honestly has been asked about a dozen of times already

Comment: You said: "On the display side, the cable oddly has 63 pins". Can you see a chip on the flex cable? You're not really interfacing to the display. You're interfacing to the display controller...assuming there is one.

Comment: Yes, @Rodo, the chip that must be the display controller is an Amlogic AML6210AP. I couldn't find its datasheet, but got the AML6210DP and I think its fair to think they work in the same way. Thanks.

Comment: As @dandavis has put it, for sure it would be cheaper to buy a brand new display+controller pair even for 20~50 bucks. But where's the fun on that? ;)